# How do i destruct object properties without mutating original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Trying to remove similar properties from array object but it throw error blocked scope variable cannot be redeclared , how i can remove similar properties from objects using any better approach without mutating original array ?

main.js

```
const loggerResponse = transformedResponse.map(({ drugName, mailPrice,retailPrice, ...rest  }) => {
    const { copayEmployer, ...mailPriceRest } = mailPrice;
    const { copayEmployer, ...retailPriceRest } = retailPrice;
    return { ...rest, mailPrice: mailPriceRest , retailPrice: retailPriceRest};
  })
```

transformedResponse

```
[
    {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Lipitor",
        "drugStrength": "80 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retialPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        }

    }, {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Metformin",
        "drugStrength": "500 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 50,
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        }
    }

]
```

expected output

```
[
    {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugStrength": "80 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retialPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        }

    }, {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugStrength": "500 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        }
    }

]
```

Comment: `map` never changes the size of the array -- it *maps* its values. If you want to remove elements, before or after mapping, `filter` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: share original json

Comment: @sarvonks data i have shared is what i am getting for transformedResponse

Comment: If you need to change the size of the array, either use `filter` or `reduce`. For your case specifically, `reduce` seems more suitable.

Comment: so it is the same Array what should be transformed ?

Comment: @SubhanAsadli yes transformedResponse should be transform into new array as i have added expected output

Comment: @amn Can you please share the approach how it would be implemented using filter

Comment: Actually, now I don't understand what's wrong with your expected output? Is it not the output you are getting with your mapping? Are you expecting something else? Do you need something else? Try to edit your question so it communicates the following clearly 1) what you have 2) what you do 3) what you get 4) what you expect to get and 5) what you want to get. As it stands, you now only communicate 1 and 2 and either 3 or 4 I am not sure. It's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your approach is great, but you need a little change, try cloning the object instead of using it directly, just like :

```
const loggerResponse = transformedResponse.map(({ drugName, mailPrice, retailPrice, ...rest  }) => {
  const { copayEmployer, ...mailPriceRest } = mailPrice || {};
  const { copayEmployer: copayEmployerRetail, ...retailPriceRest } = retailPrice || {};
  return { ...rest, mailPrice: { ...mailPriceRest, copayEmployer } , retailPrice: { ...retailPriceRest, copayEmployer: copayEmployerRetail }};
})
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution ?

```
const loggerResponse = function transform (originalArray) {
  originalArray.map( element => {
    delete element.drugName;
    delete element.mailPrice.copayEmployer;
    delete element.retialPrice.copayEmployer;
   });

  return originalArray;
}

const expectedArray = loggerResponse(transformedResponse);
console.log(expectedArray);
```

Of course you could clone the original array if you need it. And please note that just cloning with the methods like `slice()`, spread operator, etc. would not clone it deep, however you can achieve this by using the following code:

```
const deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transformedResponse));
```

Then you can perform all the operations on the cloned Array without touching the original one.

Comment: Sorry for identation